# how to merge two pandas dataframe correctly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes

df1

```
Code  Sales  Store
A       10   alpha
B        5   beta
C        4   gamma
B        3   alpha
```

df2

```
Code   Unit_Price  
A          2       
B          3     
C          4
D          5
E          6
```

I want do 2 things here.

First I want to check that all unique codes in df1 are there in df2

Second, I want to merge these 2 df2 by codes

df3, should look like

```
Code  Sales  Store   unit_price
A       10   alpha      2
B        5   beta       3
C        4   gamma      4
D        3   alpha      5
```

I did

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='Code',how='left')
```

Not sure if I am right ,  I will appreciate your time and effort to help me in this record

Comment: Please explain how the last line of your expected result is derived.  There is no Code D in df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) for check membership unique values of columns:

```
print (np.setdiff1d(df1['Code'].unique(), df1['Code'].unique()))
[]

print (np.setdiff1d(df2['Code'].unique(), df1['Code'].unique()))
['D' 'E']
```

Your solution is good, especially if need add more columns like:

```
print (df2)
  Code  Unit_Price  col
0    A           2    7
1    B           3    2
2    C           4    1
3    D           5    0
4    E           6    3

df3 = df1.merge(df2,on='Code',how='left')
print (df3)
  Code  Sales  Store  Unit_Price  col
0    A     10  alpha           2    7
1    B      5   beta           3    2
2    C      4  gamma           4    1
3    B      3  alpha           3    2
```

If need add only one column is possible use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` what should be faster:

```
df1['unit_price'] = df1['Code'].map(df2.set_index('Code')['Unit_Price'])
print (df1)
  Code  Sales  Store  unit_price
0    A     10  alpha           2
1    B      5   beta           3
2    C      4  gamma           4
3    B      3  alpha           3
```

Comment: Thamks jezrael , kindly answer my first question , how to check if df2 has all the unique codes in df1

Comment: Thank you jezrael